# apt-get not working on raspberry pi zero w [Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] ARM]

Tags: sd-card, pi-zero-w, apt, update, arm

I bought a new raspberry pi zero w. I flashed the raspbian lite image on a sd-card, the pi booted normally. But when I try to update it with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get the following error

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]
0% [2 Packages 12.4 MB/13.0 MB 95%] [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org]
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.216430] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.256761] Process http (pid: 775, stack limit = 0x079a807f)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.258879] Stack: (0xd9369c40 to 0xd936a000)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.260974] 9c40: 00000000 da4b8c38 d2e19758 d9369c58 c0117840 d9369e40 00000386 d9369da0

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.265106] 9c60: db20e4b0 00000c64 00000000 000007ff d9369da0 00000002 d9369cac d9369c88

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.269176] 9c80: c022226c c0242884 00000000 c01094e0 00000387 d9369ce8 00054b87 00000000

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.273300] 9ca0: d9369d4c d9369cb0 c0227894 c02221f4 00000800 00000000 c02226fc c011cab4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.277492] 9cc0: d9369d87 d2e19758 d9369db8 dabe2028 d2e19758 0000000f 00000393 d936010f

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.281886] 9ce0: db20ffb0 db20ffd4 db20e4b0 db20e4d4 db20ab50 db20ab74 db2198b0 db2198d4

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Aug 12 17:51:18 ...
 kernel:[  117.286529] 9d00: db215650 db215674 db2154e8 db21550c db2149f0 db214a14 db213c70 352caaa6
```

Its happening for both, `update` and `upgrade`, even when installing packages.
I also tested the with my raspberry pi 3B+ and the same sd-card and usb cable/power adapter, there works everything without errors.

Does anybody has an idea what causes this or better how to fix it?

**Possible Solution?**: The first time I tried two (different) 32GB SD-Cards. I just found another 8GB and tried it with this one. And guess what, everything worked on the first time. Just to be sure I flashed a 32GB card again and it did not work. As far as I know the pi can handle 32GB cards. Seems strange to me.

Comment: Can I ask you the SD card brand ? Because I have a similar error on rp zw with a 16GB Sandisk SD card :

    Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at May  2 08:17:20 ...
     kernel:[  213.298090] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] ARM
    
    Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at May  2 08:17:20 ...
     kernel:[  213.395870] Process kworker/u2:0 (pid: 5, stack limit = 0x4314b897)
    
    Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at May  2 08:17:20 ...
     kernel:[  213.402192] Stack: (0xdacffb40 to 0xdad00000)

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical behavior I have seen with a "weak" SD Card. It sometimes works or not maybe depending on different hardware because of very small different electrical characteristics. You wrote that you always use the same SD Card. I suggest to try with another SD Card to exclude that's not the reason.

Comment: I edited my question. You are partly right. I tried two different 32gb cards, both with the same behavior. I then found a 8gb one and gave it a try. It is from the same manufacturer as one of the 32gb cards, but it worked on the first try